# Send groovy script as a file to the Gremlin Server REST API

Tags: shell, rest, groovy, tinkerpop, gremlin-server

[Here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_connecting_via_rest) it is explained how I can interact with a Gremlin Server using its REST API. With the following command I execute the rather simple `100-1` script.

```
curl -X POST -d "{\"gremlin\":\"100-1\"}" "http://localhost:8182"
```

What I want is to instead of using an inline script, define it in say, `script.groovy`.

I can make it work for this case defining a variable with the entire script:

```
GROOVY_LOAD_DATA_SCRIPT=$(<script.groovy)
curl -X POST -d "{\"gremlin\":\"${GROOVY_LOAD_DATA_SCRIPT}\"}" "http://localhost:8182"
```

But as soon as I start moving beyond one-liners that command breaks:

```
{
    "message": "body could not be parsed"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a file called `send.groovy` that contains:

```
{
    "gremlin": "x=1+1;x+3"
}
```

I then send it via curl with:

```
$ curl -X POST --data-binary @send.groovy http://localhost:8182/gremlin
{"requestId":"6c0e7f3a-a16c-4fc1-a636-d462dc02b832","status":{"message":"","code":200,"attributes":{}},"result":{"data":[5],"meta":{}}}
```

If you want multi-line in the script itself, then you have encode the contents so that it remains valid JSON (i.e. change your line breaks to "\n" since JSON doesn't allow line-breaks).

Note that you can use tools like Python to turn the file contents into valid JSON:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo
println "Hello " + 'World!'
1+2

$ echo "{\"gremlin\":$(python -c 'import json, sys; print(json.dumps(sys.stdin.read()))' < /tmp/foo)}"
{"gremlin":"println \"Hello \" + 'World!'\n1+2\n"}
```